# Quickly finding number of minimum spanning trees in given graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I know how can one find the number of minimum spanning trees in a given graph by selectively keeping certain edges and then deleting edges to break cycles, as explained in the image below:

[image: image1 link]

However, I am struggling to apply the same method to the below graph (image below) because there will be a lot of combinations of edges for which I have to follow the above procedure. How can I easily / quickly find the number of minimum spanning trees in this graph, possibly combinatorially?

Also, is there any way to split above graph into subgraphs and the operate above procedure on those graphs separately and finally combine the count for these separate graph by taking into considerations their common edges?

[image: image2 link]

Comment: [kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem)

Comment: Kirchoff's theorem requires to calculate determinant which becomes difficult to calculate by hand if the graph involves a lot of vertices like the one shown in the image

Comment: What do you mean by 'minimum' in the context of unweighted graphs?

Comment: In un weighted graph minimum spanning tree turns out to be one with minimum number of edges

Comment: This paper describes an algorithm to enumerate the minimum spanning trees of a graph in $O(nt)$ time, where $n$ is the number of vertices and $t$ the number of spanning trees: https://www.cs.ou.edu/~thulasi/Algorithm/Complexity%20of%20Computation%20of%20a%20Spanning%20Tree%20Enumeration%20Algorithm.pdf

Comment: See *A Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm with InverseAckermann Type Complexity* by Bernard Chazelle for an algorithm to compute the MST of a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges in $O(m\alpha(m,n))$, where $\alpha$ is the inverse Ackermann function. This is essentially $O(m)$ because the Ackermann function evaluated at $A(4,4)$ is on the order of $2^{2^{2^{2^{16}}}}$.